# Website down for Just 50% of people

Tags: dns, domain-name

My website is down for just 50% of people. I have tried going through many support channels and nobody has the answer. This might be the wrong StackExchange site but it was the only I could think might know the answer.

- I am unable to access my website http://www.codebundle.net
- http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/codebundle.net thinks that my Site is up
- http://whydown.com/#codebundle.net thinks my website is up
- 50% of my friends are unable to access the website
- http://hidemyass.com is unable to access the website
- https://www.securetunnel.com/xpress is able to access the website
- tracert does not believe the site exists. returning "Unable to resolve target system name"
- The 3G (H) Network I get in this area on my phone is unable to access it
- The local costacoffee is unable to access it
- The starbucks in my nearest town is

Please help, this is really starting to annoy me

The domain is parked at godaddy until we get this fixed, then I will point it back to my site. Thank you for the assistance if you are able to help me resolve this

```
nslookup www.codebundle.net 8.8.8.8
```

returns correctly with the alias, IP and name

```
nslookup www.codebundle.net
```

has a DNS request time out and eventually just stops

I have been waiting for 3-4 months for the issue to be resolved. With no gain

Comment: what do the users see, for whom the site does not work?

Comment: it litterally just dosent load, all the people I said above. you get the same error as if you had no internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the site works, but I'll get an go daddy placeholer page. If you just now registered that page the problem might be that your computer has a old DNS record in its cache. So you need to wait or you could try to change your dns server.

Try this here to query a google dns server:

```
nslookup www.codebundle.net 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: which ISP are you with, this may be an ISP issue. if so I need to go and talk to someone at orange

Comment: I'm using Unitymedia (Germany) via Cable.

Comment: The nslookup returned the sites details and it's IP fine

Comment: If you obmit the 8.8.8.8 and get nothing than you have a dns caching problem on your IPS's dns server. Just wait in this case.

Comment: with 8.8.8.8 removed the DNS request times out. I have been waiting over 3 months talking to various people and the issue has never resolved itself. Waiting isn't doing anything for me.

Comment: Okay this is strange. Let's dig a little more I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23408/discussion-between-rekire-and-code-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

If godaddy is taking care of your domain, you should contact their support for that kind of issues.

Comment: I have, they're just giving me non answers. And aren't helping at all. I am wondering if we can isolate it to a particular ISP that is having the issue